# Background-Task for Countdown / Timer in Android activityView

Tags: android, background, timer, background-process, countdown

I created a countdown timer with a good loocking output in mm:ss

So if I switch to the activityView befor and come back to the activity with the timer, everything looks good but;-):

- timer is still running in the background - but it looks vergin, no counting..
- at this way I can start a second, third,... timer, because the button is already active

So I know that I have to set all these settings, and that it is quite normal. I have to set the

- startButon to disable - while counter runs...
- refresh the activityView if the user come back and the counter is still sctive

Maybe you can show me haw to do that for ANDROID? Herey my working code:

```
some imports....
public class BasicActivity extends Activity {


 ImageButton start, stop;
 TextView timer;




 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 //Ist dei Verbindung zur XML
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_activity);

//TIMER
    start = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    stop  = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.basicCountDown);
    timer.setText(getString(R.string.basic01)); // Platzhalter im Textfeld.

    final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(10000,1000);
    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });

}
public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        System.out.println("Timer Completed.");
        timer.setText(getString(R.string.basic02));

        //Spielt den TON ab, wenn die ZEit um ist. Siehe Methode playSound!
        playSound();



        //Notification
        new AlertDialog.Builder(BasicActivity.this).setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setMessage(getString(R.string.basicNotificationMessage)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.ButtonOK), null).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
       // dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date date = new Date(millisUntilFinished);
        timer.setText(dateFormat.format(date));

       // System.out.println("Timer  : " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
        System.out.println("Timer   : " + dateFormat.format(date));
    }
}


    //Sound nach Ablauf der Zeit
    public void playSound() {
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ton_timer);
        mp.start();

    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setEnabled(false);
            timer.start();
        }
    });

 stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        timer.cancel();
        start.setEnabled(true)
    }
});

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    System.out.println("Timer Completed.");
    timer.setText(getString(R.string.basic02));
    start.setEnabled(true);
    //Spielt den TON ab, wenn die ZEit um ist. Siehe Methode playSound!
    playSound();



//Notification
new  AlertDialog.Builder(BasicActivity.this).setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setMessage(getString(R.string.basicNotificationMessage)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.ButtonOK), null).show();
}
```

> refresh the activityView if the user come back and the counter is
>   still sctive

That's a bit tricky. Surely If you leave the Activity you should cancel the CountDownTimer or your Activity could be leak.

Comment: THX - one more question. I set a selctor with an xml for press or normal state. This works fine ;-)  So If the timer runs, the button is inactive now AND the user see the pressedClickImage - HOW can I set another image, till the timer runs???

Comment: If I have not missuderstood you, programmatically with setBackgroundResource or you can use an xml file with a selector and set the button state accordingly.